# MySQL getting result set based on two timestamp columns

Tags: php, mysql

Hope someone can help me with this one, is really staring myself blind on it.

I have a table which stores products that users have selected and in that table I store ordertime and pickedup and pickuptime. So structur is index(PRIMARY INT), ordernr(INT), ordertime(TIMESTAMP), productid(INT), pickedup(TINYINT), pickeduptime(TIMESTAMP).

Now I would love to get a result set for a graph, that says, Date, count of ordered products and count of products pickedup on, group and ordered by dates. My problem now is that I get almost right numbers, but the pickedup are counted into the ordered and I cant seem to get my head around this.

```
SELECT (case when pickedup = '1' then DATE(order_detail.pickeduptime) else DATE(order_detail.ordertime) end) AS x,COUNT(productid) AS y,SUM(case when pickedup = '1' then 1 else 0 end) AS z FROM order_detail WHERE productid = '127' AND YEAR(`ordertime`) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY x ORDER BY x asc
```

Any help would be much appriciated. :-)

UPDATED:

```
1   index   int(11)         AUTO_INCREMENT  Primary
2   ordernr int(11)         
3   productid   int(11)     
4   price   int(11)     
5   ordertime   timestamp   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
6   pickedup    tinyint(4)  0
7   pickeduptime    timestamp   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

How table looks.

Comment: Please show your table, the meaning of the colums, and tell us what graph you're trying to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that might help is proper formatting of the SQL:

```
SELECT 
  (CASE 
     WHEN pickedup = '1' THEN DATE(pickeduptime) 
     ELSE DATE(ordertime) 
   END) AS x,
  COUNT(productid) AS y,
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN pickedup = '1' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END) AS z 
FROM 
  order_detail 
WHERE 
  productid = '127' AND 
  YEAR(ordertime) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY x 
ORDER BY x ASC
```

Now I need to find out what you're trying to do. Here is where the real problems start. It is unclear whether you reuse rows in your table for the pickup or not. I'm sorry, I cannot help you. You SQL is very weird though. For something as simple as this you would not need to use two `CASE` commands.

I also cannot make sense of your SQL, grouping by a date that comes from two columns?

After careful reading I think I start to understand what you want. You want to see how many products are ordered and picked up on each date. I would not try to do that with one SQL command, but rather use two. Two lines, two SQL commands. :-)

First a simple one: How many products where ordered, grouped and sorted by date:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(ordertime) as orderdate,
  COUNT(productid) AS quantity
FROM 
  order_detail 
WHERE 
  productid = '127' AND 
  YEAR(ordertime) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY orderdate 
ORDER BY orderdate ASC
```

Now the ordered products that are not yet picked up:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(ordertime) as orderdate,
  COUNT(productid) AS quantity
FROM 
  order_detail 
WHERE 
  productid = '127' AND 
  YEAR(ordertime) = YEAR(NOW()) AND
  pickedup != '1'
GROUP BY orderdate 
ORDER BY orderdate ASC
```

and now the products that have been picked up, still sorted on order date:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(ordertime) as orderdate,
  COUNT(productid) AS quantity
FROM 
  order_detail 
WHERE 
  productid = '127' AND 
  YEAR(ordertime) = YEAR(NOW()) AND
  pickedup = '1'
GROUP BY orderdate 
ORDER BY orderdate ASC
```

And here's the same sorted on pickup date:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(pickeduptime) as pickedupdate,
  COUNT(productid) AS quantity
FROM 
  order_detail 
WHERE 
  productid = '127' AND 
  YEAR(ordertime) = YEAR(NOW()) AND
  pickedup = '1'
GROUP BY pickedupdate
ORDER BY pickedupdate ASC
```

Now you can use any of these to draw a line in your graph.

If you insist on one query you could use this one:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(ordertime) as orderdate,
  SUM(pickedup) AS pickedup_quantity,
  SUM(1-pickedup) AS not_pickedup_quantity
FROM 
  order_detail 
WHERE 
  productid = '127' AND 
  YEAR(ordertime) = YEAR(NOW())  
GROUP BY orderdate 
ORDER BY orderdate ASC
```

Note that everything has to be sorted by one date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im sorry, but my mysql advance skills are lacking and this is just what I got from that, and I know it is not super good.
I'm using one row for each ordered product and are updating the pickedup value and the pickeduptime, when customer picks it up from the store.

Comment: Ah, I see, now I understand how that works. Can you explain what you want to show in your Graph? I need to know how you want to represent ordered and picked up products in your graph. Mixed but ordered on date? It makes little sense to me.

Comment: Im using Morris.js and want a graph with date as the x axis and y axis with 2 lines, the number of products ordered on that day and the number of products pickedup on that date.
http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?js,output

Comment: Thanks so far, but was really hoping it could be done in one query, so it is easy to put directly into the graph. With 2 querys I will have to find a way to merge them and feed them into the graph, so they come out like;
[{"0":"2014-10-04","x":"2014-10-04","1":"210","y":"210","2":"16","z":"16"}] and so on.

Comment: I don't think one query is possible, and even if it is, it will be very ugly. Please use two queries in this case, it is the logical solution. After that it should not be difficult to merge the two SQL results into one javascript graph. Ask a new question if you find that difficult.

Comment: I added a query in my answer if you insist on using one query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your problem exactly, but I think you've got a syntax error : forgot to put a "CASE" after the "END", as in [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: My problem is that I get a list, but it is incorrect, the pickedup are counted into the "y" variable, but it should be like this:
Date, number of products order on this date, number of products pickedup on this date.